# Swap 2 chars in assembly using the stack and pointers

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I wrote a function that should swap to chars, the function gets parameters by pushing pointers of the two chars into the stack.
When I print the chars it stays the same and I don't understand what is the problem here.
my function:

```
PROC swap
    ;start frame 
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    ;swap
    mov ax, 98;ax='b'
    mov [bp+6], ax;*ch1=ch2
    mov ax, 0
    mov al, temp;temp=*num1
    mov [bp+4], ax;*ch2=temp 

    ;close frame
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    retn 4   
ENDP swap
```

my main:

```
jmp main
    toSwap1     db 'a'
    toSwap2     db 'b'
    temp        db 'a';used to swap the values
main:   
    push ax
    lea ax,[toSwap1]
    push ax

    lea ax,[toSwap2]
    push ax 

    call swap

    pop ax
    mov al,toSwap1
    call print_al_chr
```

function to print char:

```
print_al_chr    proc
        pusha
        _PRINT_AL_CHR
        popa
        ret
print_al_chr    endp
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve]. What is `temp`? How are you printing something?

Comment: I added the details you asked for in the question

Comment: First obvious issue is that if you intend to be able to swap any two chars, you must not have a hardcoded `b` in your function. Also, since you are trying to swap the things pointed to, you must never write to the pointers themselves - you need to read the pointers and dereference them. `temp` is not needed and initializing it to `a` is again bad for being general.

Comment: How can I dereference the pointers?
what do you mean " you need to read the pointers and dereference them"

Comment: E.g.  you can load them into `si` and `di` and then use `[si]` and `[di]` to dereference.

Comment: Ok I will try it now